# dynamic dojo textfield creation in div with ajax?

Tags: javascript, ajax, jsp, dojo

when i  run with  welcome.jsp, dojo creates a textbox dynamically.but when i call the welcome.jsp with ajax in index.jsp, which shows only div element.which doesn't create a text field inside that div........... please someone help me? 
hear is the code.

```
                            index.jsp



<!DOCTYPE html>
<%@page import="java.util.*" %> <%@page import="org.hibernate.*,org.hibernate.cfg.*,example.*" %>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojo/dojo.js"  data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo-release-1.9.2-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo-release-1.9.2-src/dojo/resources/dojo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo-release-1.9.2-src/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
<script>
require(["dojox/layout/ContentPane"]);
function showCustomer(str)
{
var xmlhttp;    
if (str=="")
  {
  document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML="";
  return;
  }
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
  {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
  xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
  }
else
  {// code for IE6, IE5
  xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
  }
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
  {
  if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
    {
    document.getElementById("txtHint").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
    }
  }
  alert("str is"+str);
xmlhttp.open("GET","welcome.jsp",true);
xmlhttp.send();
alert(4);
}
</script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">

<form action=""> 
<select name="customers" onchange="showCustomer(this.value)">
<option value="">Select a customer:</option>


<option value="customer1">customer1</option>    

</select>
</form>
<br>
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="txtHint" data-dojo-props="href: '/welcome.jsp', executeScripts: true">
    Customer info will be listed here...
</div>

</body>
</html>

                    welcome.jsp

<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<%@page import="java.util.*" %> <%@page import="org.hibernate.*,org.hibernate.cfg.*,example.*" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Dojo DnD test</title>


    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/dojo/1.7/dojo/dojo.js"  data-dojo-config="parseOnLoad: true, isDebug: true"></script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo-release-1.9.2-src/dijit/themes/claro/claro.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo-release-1.9.2-src/dijit/themes/claro/document.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="dojo-release-1.9.2-src/dijit/themes/claro/dijitTests.css">
    <body onload="vali();">
    </body>
<script>
dojo.require("dojo.dnd.Source");
dojo.require("dijit.form.TextBox");
dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
require(["dojox/layout/ContentPane"]);
var widgets = new Array();
var source;
var c=new Array();


dojo.ready(function() {




 for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
     widgets.push(
     new dijit.form.TextBox({
         value: i,
         class: 'dojoDndItem',
     }).placeAt("source"));
 }

 source = new dojo.dnd.Source("source", {
     copyOnly: false
 });
 new dojo.dnd.Source("target");
});
setValue = function() {
    widgets[0].attr("value", (new Date).getTime());
};

insertNew = function() {
 widgets.push(
    new dijit.form.TextBox({
        value: widgets.length,
        class: 'dojoDndItem',
    }));

    source.insertNodes(true, [widgets[widgets.length-1].domNode]);
};
</script>

</head>
<body class="claro">
<form name="form1">
    <div dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="setValue">
    set value textbox 0
</div>
<div dojoType="dijit.form.Button" onClick="insertNew">
    insert new textbox
</div>
<table>
<tr>
<td>
<div id="source" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid red;">

</div>  </td>
<td><div id="target" style="height: 200px; width: 200px; border: 1px solid blue;">

</div></td></tr></table>

</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because when you load your content with AJAX, scripts are not interpreted. You have to evaluate them by yourself using the `eval()` function. Or, since you're using Dojo, you could look at the [`dojox/layout/ContentPane`](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojox/layout/ContentPane.html) module. This module allows you to load a page (through AJAX requests) and execute the scripts that are on it without the entire `XMLHttpRequest` or `ActiveXObject` overhead (and without having to manually call `eval()`).

To do this with the `dojox/layout/ContentPane`, you just replace your `<div>` with ID `#txtHint` by:

```js
<div data-dojo-type="dojox/layout/ContentPane" id="txtHint" data-dojo-props="href: 'welcome.jsp', executeScripts: true">
    Customer info will be listed here...
</div>
```

You only need to make sure you load Dojo, set the `data-dojo-config` attribute so that `parseOnLoad: true` property is set and you need to make sure you import the `dojox/layout/ContentPane` module by having the following code:

```js
require(["dojox/layout/ContentPane", "dojo/parser"]);
```

A full example loading a webpage can be found on [this JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/FBP7w/) (I change the `href` to `/` so it would load the homepage again, because I have no `welcome.jsp` page).

Another example doing the same programmatically can be found on this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/39sNu/1/).

Comment: can you tell me how to add dojox/layout/ContentPane module to my code?

Comment: I updated my answer with a solution using the `dojox/layout/ContentPane` module. I also noticed your previous comment, to answer that: it's not easy to do with `eval()`. You would have to parse the response string and get all code between `<script>` tags and use `eval()` on that part.

Comment: As you said,i have added the code to my program but it is not working

Comment: I have edited the code and removed scriptlet code,i am calling only calling welcome.jsp in index.jsp through ajax.when i run welcome.jsp it works fine,when i call through ajax it doesn't create textbox.

Comment: Can you also tell me what you mean by "not working"? Is it showing errors, not executing the JavaScript on the page, ... .

Comment: It is not executing javascript?

Comment: I have pasted modified code (index.jsp,welcome.jsp) in this page,please consider.In welcome.jsp it executes dojo fine,but when i call through ajax,dojo doesn't work

Comment: The contentpane acts as a replacement of your `showCustomer()` code, I'm not sure if you're still using it or not? If you want to see an example setting the `welcome.jsp` page programmatically, you can check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/39sNu/

Comment: It displays error "Error: Could not load class 'dojox/layout/ContentPane"

Comment: Can you also try to add `dojo/parser` to your `require()` so it becomes `require(["dojox/layout/ContentPane"]);`?

Comment: I have added these module before.but it shows same error